# How do I select a tag with a given attribute whose value is unknown?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm guessing this is a trivial question for someone with a bit of experience with Nokogiri, but I haven't been able to find an answer in the documentation or tutorials I've found online.

I have a Nokogiri document like this:

```ruby
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.example.com"))
```

And the page contains the following tag:

```html
<a title="could be anything" href="http://www.example.com/foo"></a>
```

How do I get the value of `href` if the value of `title` is unknown?

Comment: But you need something as an reference to get the value of `href`,if any specific you want to extract. or if you want all then nothing needed,there are ways to get all. First confirm me.

Comment: I want to use the title key as the reference. The value of title is unknown. I think this requires an XPath solution but I've been using CSS selectors. I can use this:
    page.xpath('//a[@title]')
to get the value of all titles, but I don't want the value of title. I'm trying to find the value of the sibling attribute for 'href'.

Comment: So you want to select the `href` of all `a` elements having a `title` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the value of the `href` attribute for `a` elements having a `title` attribute you can use Nokogiri's `xpath` as follows:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(File.open('sample.html'))

a_with_title = doc.xpath('//a[@title]').map { |e| puts e['href'] }
```

If you want to select from an URL online you can use

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://stackoverflow.com/'))

a_with_title = doc.xpath('//a[@title]').map { |e| puts e['href'] }
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution for my project. Thank you!

Comment: Use `doc.xpath('//a[@title]').map{ |n| n['href'] }`.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks. I understand why it makes sense to be more concise but why `map` instead of `each`? Is it implied by the question? The question is rather unclear.

Comment: Think of it this way: `map` returns an array that can be reused however is needed, including passing to `puts` which will output the array, each element on a single line. The visual output is the same as what you were using `each` and `puts` to do, only `map` would give you the ability to chain and do more. I almost never use `each` to print as I'm developing, simply because I usually find I want to chain something else to `map`. In your code, `puts a_with_title` will output everything, or let you continue processing `a_with_title` as an array. Don't `puts` inside `map`, use `e['href']` alone.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. I believe, the following will work to select the `href` from the first link element with a title attribute: `page.css('a[title]')[0]['href']`.

I had thought `page.css('a[title]')` was selecting the value of the `title` attribute, but in fact it selects the entire element. You can then reference this element to get values from it.

Comment: `page.at('a[title]')` is the proper method to use; It does the same thing as `page.css('a[title]')[0]` under the covers.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'nokogiri'


doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse <<-SCRIPT
<a title="xx" href="http://www.example1.com/foo1"></a>
<a title="aa" href="http://www.example2.com/foo2"></a>
<a id=5 href="http://www.foo.com/foo3"></a>
<a title="zz" href="http://www.example3.com/foo4"></a>
<a id=5 href="http://www.test.com/foo5"></a>
 SCRIPT

p doc.search("a").map { |nd|  nd['href'] if nd.key?('title')}.compact

#=> ["http://www.example1.com/foo1", "http://www.example2.com/foo2", "http://www.example3.com/foo4"]
```

Comment: Could you please include an explanation of the code? How does it compare to the other solutions?

Comment: @N.N. okay! which part made you confused? tell me I will give you the explanation. This is another way to do the same thing.

Comment: So it is not more effective or better in any other way? Well, I am quote new to Nokogiri and I have never seen `DocumentFragment` nor its `search` before.

Comment: @N.N. `#search` is mostly used concept in `nokogiri` like `#xpath`.

Comment: nice, succinct, solution. I wasn't aware of many of these methods. Thank you.

Comment: `doc.search("a").map { |nd|  nd['href'] if nd.key?('title')}.compact` is not a good way to accomplish this. `search('a[title]')` will find all `<a>` tags containing a `title` parameter.

Comment: @N.N., [`Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse()`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/HTML/DocumentFragment.html) will parse the HTML, but not wrap it in `<html>` or `<body>` tags.

Comment: @theTinMan thanks for the post tips as always. But `p doc.search("a[title]")` giving me `[]`.

Comment: Use `doc.css('a[title]')` and you won't need the trailing `map` or `compact`. `search` is generic and lets Nokogiri decide whether it should treat the accessor as CSS or XPath. In this case I think Nokogiri gets confused and does the wrong thing. `css` forces it to treat the accessor as a CSS pattern, which will return only `<a>` tags with a `title` parameter. As a result you don't have to embed a conditional inside `map`, which is the cause of you getting `nil` elements in the returned array, forcing you to use `compact`.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks for advance things to tell me,But my code also returned expected result. Any guess why down-vote?

Comment: I'd say it's because `doc.search("a").map { |nd|  nd['href'] if nd.key?('title')}.compact` is not the Ruby-way to do it. It doesn't show an understanding of how Nokogiri, CSS accessors and `map` work, and `compact` just proves that. Ruby is capable of very elegant, concise, and readable code. People often say good Ruby code is "Zen-like", meaning we end up meditating on it and see power in a little bit of very clear code. That's what we should try to achieve in all our code; clear, concise, readable code.

Comment: @theTinMan thanks for your reply back.I am just now learning `nokogiri`, so I am trying to use its every method to see how they work. Thus i wrote the above. Anyway thank you very much :)

Comment: @theTinMan just one more tips I want from you - when to think of `Nokogiri::HTML::Document` and when should I `Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment`? As `Nokogiri::HTML.parse(open('http://www.goibibo.com/flight-searchresult/#air-CCU-HYD-20130420-20130422-1-0-0-E'))` is working but the other one throwing an error.

Comment: Common use is `Nokogiri::HTML(string_to_parse)` and let Nokogiri add `html` and `body` tags as necessary. Use `Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(...)` when you must have ONLY the content and nothing else.